# Support Different Vendored Frameworks for Simulator vs iOS Device

Tags: cocoapods, podspec

I am trying to write a PodSpec that allows us to use one framework `JellyFrameworkForDefice.framework` when installing to a device and another framework `JellyFrameworkForSimulator.framework` when installing to a simulator via Xcode.  Does anyone have any ideas around this or have examples they have seen where this has worked before?

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'Jelly'
  s.module_name      = 'Jelly'
  s.version          = '1.0.3'
  s.summary          = 'Jelly 4.1.2'
  s.description      = <<-DESC
     TODO: Add long description of the pod here.
                   DESC
  s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/<GITHUB_USERNAME>/Jelly'
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { '' => '' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/<GITHUB_USERNAME>/Jelly', :tag => s.version.to_s }
  s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'
  s.source_files = 'Jelly/Classes/**/*.h', 'Jelly/Classes/**/*.m',  'Jelly/Classes/**/*.mm'
  s.resources = 'Jelly/Assets/UX_Resources/*', 'Jelly/Classes/UX/Resources/*'
  s.libraries        = 'c++'
  s.vendored_framework = 'Jelly/Libraries/JellyFrameworkForDefice.framework', 'Jelly/Libraries/JellyFrameworkForSimulator.framework'
  s.dependency 'Cordova', '4.2.1'
  s.dependency 'DependencyContainer'
  s.dependency 'JellyService'
  s.compiler_flags = '-lstdc++', '-lc++'
  s.ios.framework  = 'AudioToolbox', 'AVFoundation', 'CoreGraphics', 
          'CoreMedia', 'CoreVideo', 'MobileCoreServices', 'OpenGLES', 
          'QuartzCore', 'Security', 'ImageIO', 'Foundation', 'UIKit'
  s.xcconfig = { 'OTHER_LDFLAGS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => '$(inherited) -framework "JellyFrameworkForSimulator"',
'OTHER_LDFLAGS[sdk=iphoneos*]' => '$(inherited) -framework "JellyFrameworkForDefice"' }
end
```

Comment: You can have one framework with different architecture slices.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien yes a very valid point, I will make the recommendation to the framework provider but in all likely hood it will continue to be two frameworks :(